# How to save checkbox value as string with Formly?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-formly

I am currently using Formly to generate checkboxes. When a checkbox is ticked, the value is saved as true but I need it to be as a string like this "true". I also use a JSON to generate the checkboxes which makes it harder to manipulate the HTML values.

See this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formly-checkbox?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Is there a way to get the value as string instead of boolean?

Comment: The only way I can think of is by writing a custom ValueAccessor. But since there is no way in Formly to pass a directive to a type you'll probably need to write a custom Formly component as well. And since you're using Material probably also a custom Material component. That's a lot of work for a requirement I honestly find a bit weird. Why do you need to treat a boolean value as a string in the first line?

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of **true** values:
For that just set `type`  to `array` inside `templateOptions`

```
 templateOptions: {
     type: 'array',
     // other options
 }
```